# Does the phrase "$y$ depends on $x$" usually mean $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, terminology

While I have asked my colleagues this question I came up with while writing a paper, I wanted to ask here as well:

Given two variables $x$ and $y$, can we assume that the phrase "$y$ depends on $x$" usually means $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$?

Any feedback is welcome, thank you for your time.

Comment: Not generally, it can mean that the value of $x$ restricts the possibilities for $y$. For example if we want $y+x > 0$, $y$ depends on $x$ but $y$ isn't necessarily defined through a unique function on $x$

Comment: Also, of course, it could mean that $x$ is but one variable of many, $y=f(x,u,v,w).$

Comment: Writing it that way suggest an *explicit* form, though of course you might only have an *implicit* dependence, as in $e^{xy}+x^2y+y^3=1$.

Comment: As the examples in the above comments state, not necessarily but it is in many cases. In what context are you stating this dependency in your paper?

Comment: @lulu - Quick follow up question (Thomas was not able to get back to me, so if you have time it would be greatly appreciated): given $y = f(x, u, v, w)$ could we say that "$y$ depends on $x$" to emphasize this particular dependence in a situation without having to say "$y$ depends on $x$, $u$, $v$, and $w$"? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, I think that would usually be fine.  In situations where it might be misleading, you could elaborate a bit and say something like "$y$ depends on $x$, among other factors".  For instance, it's fine to say that "sensitivity to certain diseases depends on the age of the patient" as nobody is likely to imagine that age is the *unique* relevant factor.

Comment: In natural language I've heard people say "[quantity] is a function of [quantity]" to mean that the latter impacts the former. Interestingly, it kinda forgets that constant functions are technically functions. (But it's close enough for a short phrase, I suppose.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all who contributed in the comments, here is an answer - consisting of those comments - to close this question:

In conclusion, I wouldn't write "$y$ depends on $x$" and assume the reader knows I mean $y = f(x)$ without already writing $y=f(x)$ first. Additionally, if you say "$y$ depends on $x$" first without further context a few things should be accounted for:

1. (as lulu states): "Writing it that way suggests an *explicit* form, though of course you might only have an *implicit* dependence..."
2. (as Thomas Andrews states): "...of course, it could mean that $x$ is but one of many, $y = f(x,u,v,w)$."

Note for point 2): Given $y = f(x,u,v,w)$ one could say "$y$ depends on $x$" to emphasize this particular dependence in a situation without having to state each variable $y$ depends on. However, in situations where it might be misleading we could elaborate and say something like "$y$ depends on $x$, *among other factors*" (lulu).